# To write dataframe without index get wrong format

Tags: python-3.x, excel, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
df
                     year        2022       2021
0  return on equity (roe)     160.90%    144.10%
1          average equity  62027.9677  65704.372
2       net profit margin      0.2531     0.2588
3                turnover      1.1179     1.0422
4                leverage       5.687     5.3421
```

I want to write it into excel without index:

```
df.to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx',index=False)
```

Why there is a empty cell at the left-up corner in the `test.xlsx` file?

[image]

How can get the below format with `to_excel` method?

[image]

It is no use to add header argument.

```
df.to_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx', index=False, header=True)
```

Now read from the excel:

```
new_df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx',index_col=False)
new_df
               Unnamed: 0        year       2022  2021
0  return on equity (roe)     160.90%    144.10%   NaN
1          average equity  62027.9677  65704.372   NaN
2       net profit margin      0.2531     0.2588   NaN
3                turnover      1.1179     1.0422   NaN
4                leverage       5.687     5.3421   NaN
```

Can't add header argument when reading:

```
new_df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/test.xlsx',index_col=False,header=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 490, in read_excel
    data = io.parse(
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1734, in parse
    return self._reader.parse(
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 732, in parse
    validate_header_arg(header)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 203, in validate_header_arg
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Include the header parameter as true:

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=True)
```

[image]

---

Back to a df, set index_col parameter to none:

```
new_df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',index_col=None)
print(new_df)

                     year        2022       2021
0  return on equity (roe)     160.90%    144.10%
1          average equity  62027.9677  65704.372
2       net profit margin      0.2531     0.2588
3                turnover      1.1179     1.0422
4                leverage       5.687     5.3421
```

Comment: It is the same result with  pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',index_col=False) in my pc.

Comment: Worked for me as you can see @newview. Just tested it again, no problems here.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason,the dataframe for the example is special:

```
df.columns
MultiIndex([('year',),
            ('2022',),
            ('2021',)],
           )
```

It's not a single index.

```
df.columns = ['year', '2022', '2021']
df.to_excel('/tmp/test.txt',index=False)
```

The strange phenomenon disappeared at last.
`dataframe` with multiIndex `[('year',),('2022',),('2021',)]` display the same appearance such as single index `['year', '2022', '2021']` in my case.